# How to wrap text around floating, fixed image?

Tags: html, css, image, css-float

I've got an image that floats in the bottom right corner (to put in the button, the position has to be fixed). However, part of the text on my page disappears behind the image. Is it possible to make this text wrap around my image?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
 <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png' 
style='float:right;
position: fixed;
right:50px; 
bottom:50px;
width:20%'>
Text is placed here
</body>
</html>
```

You can see the problem in action on this [example page](http://smc.webege.com/stackoverflow.html).

Comment: No, I can’t see the problem on your example page. – It’s gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not in CSS alone.

The fact that the image is floated doesn't help here, because it is also fixed. Therefor it is not part of the flow anymore and the text doesn't respond to it.

This cannot be fixed by CSS alone. You could fix it using Javascript by moving the image around as you scroll, but it will be hard to get right and it will seriously slow down scrolling through your page, since the text will have to be re-aligned after each movement.

I think you'd better look out for a different solution.

Comment: I've looked for mmany different solutions, but I couldn't find a proper one. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: I think you could do something with a right floated div that has about the size of your image. That div can be inserted in the text at a certain position. Which position is something you need to find out using Javascript. To do that, you have to hide the div, get a text position based on the visible area of your content and then insert the div in that position in the text again. It should be possible, but like I said, it's going to be hard to get right and will probably slow down rendering as well.

Answer (score 1):

when you use a position fixed or absolute (float here is irrelevant for your style, you could remove it) you're removing an element from its natural flow. Thus, given this position, the text is not able to detect the image and to re-arrange itself around it.

Answer (score -3):

Using Z-index property you can do this..

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ec/Happy_smiley_face.png' 
    style='float:right;
    position: fixed;
    z-index:-100;
    right:50px; 
    bottom:50px;
    width:20%'>
    <p style="z-index:12000">
    Text is placed here</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Nope, that just makes the text go on top of the image. Still no wrapping :(