# Make div button over contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, contenteditable

I am developping an angular app for a client, and I have to make a clickable button at the bottom right over a contenteditable element like the following image :

[image]

To add some difficulty, the content should be scrollable, but the button should stay a the same place and the text should avoid it.
Of course, I can't add some marging/padding cause it will add some blank column/line at the bottom or at the right of the content editable zone.

I can use any js/css tips/library.

EDIT #1 :
Ok I was not enough accurate with my question. 
Here is some code :

```
<p id="editfield"  contenteditable="true"></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4yr7jsz1/24/

As you can see, this is a "contenteditable" element. So the user can type come text in it. But the text should not pass below the round button, and it should be srcollable.

EDIT #2 :
Actually, I am almost good with the button. The ":before" element on the inserted element inside the contenteditale container allow me to place the zone I want the text to avoid. But the problem is I can't change any aprameter af a ":before" element via javascript...
Here is the html :

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div id="editable-content" ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <span id="clickable-zone"></span>
    <p id="editfield" contenteditable="true"></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

The #clickable-zone is the button.

Via javascript, I insert an empty element that will make the text goes around.

```
app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var imgPhoto = $('<div class="inside_element"></div>');
      var mydiv = $('<div class="myimage"></div>').append(imgPhoto);


      element.bind("blur keyup change", function(event) {
        if(element.html() != mydiv[0].outerHTML && element.html() != '') {
                    mydiv.prependTo(element);
        }
        else {
          mydiv.remove();
        }
      });

      $(document).on("click","span#clickable-zone",function() {
        console.log('click');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then, I add css for all the different content that will let me position the "blank zone" inside the contenteditable element.

```
[contenteditable] {
  border: 2px dotted #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inside_element {
  float:right;
  clear:both;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.myimage:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float:right;
  height: 100px;
}

#clickable-zone {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float:right;
  background-image: url("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Prevent showing multiple background images*/
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#editable-content {
  height: 208px;
  width: 508px;
  position: relative;
}
```

I am not sure that there is a way to do it, any help would be great :)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: This is not possible with pure CSS, you can't have a fixed element which still would be a part of the textflow. Also, when the button should be in a contenteditable, a script would have limited access to the content.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182577/how-to-wrap-text-around-floating-fixed-image

Comment: _You could fix it using Javascript by moving the image around as you scroll, but it will be hard to get right and it will seriously slow down scrolling through your page, since the text will have to be re-aligned after each movement.

I think you'd better look out for a different solution._

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. Yes, thats exactly what I try to avoid, moving the button with javascript. My exemple is almost what I need (http://jsfiddle.net/4yr7jsz1/23/) , but I am blocked with the ":before" element on the image container, cause there is no way to change its height with javacript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally find my answer by finding a way to move the "before" peuso element inside the contenteditable element.
Here is the code snippet :

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('SimpleController', function($scope){

});

app.directive("contenteditable", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var imgPhoto = $('<div class="inside_element"></div>');
      var mydiv = $('<div class="myimage"></div>').append(imgPhoto);
      
      var initScrollHeight = element[0].scrollHeight;
      var initAvoidElementHeight = 100;
      
      element.bind("blur keyup change scroll", function(event) {
       var position = element[0].scrollHeight;
  if(element[0].scrollTop > 0) {
         var position = element[0].scrollTop + initScrollHeight;
        }
        else if(element[0].scrollHeight > initScrollHeight) {
         var position = initScrollHeight;
        }

       var diffScroll = parseInt(position - initScrollHeight);
        mydiv.css('height', initAvoidElementHeight + diffScroll);
    
        if(element.html() != mydiv[0].outerHTML && element.html() != '') {
      mydiv.prependTo(element);
        }
        else {
            mydiv.remove();
        }
        
      });

      $(document).on("click","span#clickable-zone",function() {
       console.log('click');
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```css
[contenteditable] {
  border: 2px dotted #ccc;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.inside_element {
  float:right;
  clear:both;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.myimage::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  float:right;
  height: inherit;
}
.myimage {
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 0;
}
#clickable-zone {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  float:right;
  background-image: url("https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300");
  background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Prevent showing multiple background images*/
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#editable-content {
  height: 208px;
  width: 508px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div id="editable-content" ng-controller="SimpleController">
    <span id="clickable-zone"></span>
    <p id="editfield"  contenteditable="true" ></p>
  </div>
</body>
```

As you can see, I used the inherit css trick to pass the dynamic height of the before pseudo element.
The scroll is still working and I can't see any lack of performance right now.
Hope this can help someone one day :)

Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I was trying to work out an answer in that lines, but it seems that you've done it before me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution,
The button remains as fixed,while the content gets scrolled.
https://jsfiddle.net/8rofx1n9/2/

```css
.btn{

  float:right;
  position:fixed;
  margin-left:300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
Text Goes here
<span > <input class="btn" type="button" value="ClickMe"   >   

<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
Contents.........


<br/><br/><br/><br/>
Contents.........


<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
Contents.........


<br/><br/><br/><br/>
Contents.........

<br/><br/><br/><br/>
Contents.........

</span>


</html>
```